# Cannot POST / on express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm Building an Dashboard for a Discord Bot in javascript. After sending login Token it says "Cannot POST /". I searched on google but nothing Helped...

I tried some Codes from other questions on Stackoverflow but it wont work for me.

**anmelden.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Anmelden: WumpyBot Webinterface</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#0049ff">
    <center><br><br>
        <h2>Anmelden</h2>
        <h3>Bitte gebe deinen Anmeldecode ein. Dieser gilt 10 Minuten lang und kann auf dem ausgewählten Discord Server mit dem Befehl "/wi generate" erzeugt werden.</h3>
        <form action="http:/"+"/194.93.56.2:8080/anmelden" method="POST"> <input type="text" name="anmeldecode"><button type="submit">Anmelden</button> </form>
        <br>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Webserver(Filename.js)**

```
const express = require('express'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
const path = require('path'); 
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Discord.Client(); 
const app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.post('/example', (req, res) => { 
    res.send(`Full name is:${req.body.fname} ${req.body.lname}.`); 
}); 
app.post('/prefixchange', (req, res) => { 
    res.send(`Neuer Prefix: ${req.body.prefix}.`); 
}); 
app.post('/nicknamechange', (req, res) => { 
    res.send(`Neuer Name: ${req.body.nickname}.`); 
}); 
app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/anmelden.html'));
}); 
app.post('/anmelden', (req, res) => { 
    var anmeldecode = req.body.anmeldecode; 
    console.log("Anmeldung: "+anmeldecode); 
});
app.post('/anmeldg', function(req, res) { 
    if (req.body.anmeldecode == "ADMIN") {
        res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname+'/wumpy.html');
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname+'/anmeldeerror.html');
    }
}); 
app.get('/interface', (req, res) => { 
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname+'wumpy.html');
}); 
app.get('/beta', (req, res) => { 
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname+'index.html');
}); 

app.listen(80, () => { 
    console.info('Running on port 80');
});

var guilds = []
client.guilds
    .forEach(guild => {
        guilds.push({id: guild.id, name: guild.name})
    })


app.use((err, req, res, next) => { 
    switch (err.message) { 
        case 'NoCodeProvided': 
            return res.status(400).send({ 
                status: 'ERROR', 
                error: err.message, 
                }); 
                default: 
                    return res.status(500).send({ 
                        status: 'ERROR', 
                        error: err.message, 
                    }); 
    }
});
```

I locked up into console but nothing there, only `Running on port 80`

Comment: change call link from "http:/"+"/194.93.56.2:8080/anmelden" to 'http://194.93.56.2:8080/anmelden'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't declared a post request for / route. please declare a route for the url that you are posting the request on

Comment: He's trying to post to anmelden, look at his code plox.

Answer (score 0):

have you even inspected your code? or is this a SO typo

```
<form action="http:/"+"/194.93.56.2:8080/anmelden" method="POST"> <input type="text" name="anmeldecode"><button type="submit">Anmelden</button> </form>
```

the action is broken; it targets "http:/" the rest would be seen as a separate prop, why is that + there.

Also like some said, your express is configured for port 80, and you're posting to 8080 (or you would be if your html wasn't screwed up).

Try using a proper IDE for your HTML if that helps, JSFiddle even throws warnings with that HTML